# HTML href=" " vs onclick="self.location.href=' ' "

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I came across this JS code:

```
onClick="self.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/'"
```

I have used this in my website and it has the same function like the `href` attribute.

I am new in JS and I do not know much about JS, but there may be a difference between the `onclick="self.location.href=''"` and `href=""` attribute.

What is the difference?

What are the benefits and what are the disadvantages?

Comment: You shouldn't be using any of them, you should use proper event handlers instead.

Comment: There's no good reason to use JS to duplicate the natural behaviour of the `href` attribute of an anchor tag. Use JS only to add extra behaviour beyond the default navigation.

Comment: Why would you ever need to use either of these? Or are the blanks in your example meant to be `[some url]`?

Comment: This prevents users from middle clicking to open in a new tab. That's about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first benefit of using href tag would be for the search engines. Most of the search engines detect `href` attribute and crawl your website, the other thing would be if the user disabled their javascript in their browser, `self.location.href` wont work. But the `href` attribute only works with the `a` tag, so when you want to redirect a user when clicking on a button for example, you can not use `href` attribute as button tag or input tag wont accept href attribute, so you should use `window.location` or `self.location`

Comment: So are you saying `onclick=function` actually will work if javascript is disabled, and that search engines will follow javascript in the href tag ?

Comment: onclick=funtion only works when javascript is enabled, and search engines will follow href attribute on a tag

Comment: "you can not use href attribute as button tag or input tag wont accept href attribute" - yes, but it is important to remember that you can always put button between a tags and then use the attribute,